# Requirements of dedicated broadcast channel in Joint-Feldman protocol

Tags: key-generation, broadcast-encryption

I am currently reading through [Secure Distributed Key Generation For Discrete-Log Based Cryptosystems](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.2737&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which describes a secure variant of the Joint-Feldman protocol. In this paper, in section 2 (Preliminaries), it's stated that the communication model assumes the participants have access to a "dedicated broadcast channel". However, the definition for this is never given anywhere in the paper.

Does anyone know what the precise requirements are for this "dedicated broadcast channel", and would be able to provide a reference? Thank you!